# Value in Tiptap-Editor does not change when using a reusable tiptap-react-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor, richtext, tiptap

I have made an app where I use a reusable component. In this component I am rendering the TipTap-Editor.
In this app you can toggle between the two reusable components and they get other values as props.

If you try out the app and click the button "show banana editor", the content in TipTap does not change and I don't know why.
I also tried to add a dependency-array with "value" and "setValue". The app crashes by doing so.

Please find an example with this link at CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/alexmuzenhardt/tiptap-codesandbox/main

If anybody could help, this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you and all the best
Alex

I also tried to add a dependency-array with "value" and "setValue". The app crashes by doing so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.